# autoconf: check a specific library

Tags: autoconf

I am struggling a bit to get Autoconf to perform a desired check. Consider the use-case where a version of a package has been installed in the standard locations - its header is in `/usr/include`, and its library in `/usr/lib`. The user has installed a different version of the package in `/home/package`, with the include file in /home/package/include and the library in `/home/package/lib`.

A typical way of handling this is to add a `--with-package=/home/package` option to configure. In order to protect against typos and to ensure that the specified package is operational, the configure code would use `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` to test the header, and `AC_SEARCH_LIB` or `AC_CHECK_LIB` for the library.

The problem I'm having is in constraining Autoconf to look solely at the provided locations instead of picking up the installation in the standard location. I have tried:

- setting `CPPFLAGS=-I/home/package` for `AC_CHECK_HEADERS`, but that didn't resolve the problem. Only workaround I could find so far is to test if the include file exists - `test -f $with_package/include/package.h` - but that seems awfully fragile and renders `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` moot.
- setting `LDFLAGS=-L/home/package/lib` and clearing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` prior to calling `AC_SEARCH_LIB`, but that didn't constrain the search. It still picks up the standard location. Ditto for `AC_CHECK_LIB`.

Note that the compiler and linker do pickup the correct version of the package if the `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` get correctly set, as verified (for example) by running ldd on the final result.

Any suggestions? Or is just checking for file and lib existence the only real option here?

Comment: Not sure, if it's helpful, but I just checked: both the boost.m4 as well as sdl.m4 macros to detect libsdl2 and the boost library offer a `--with-X=Y` switch that, once set, tries to detect X solely in Y and fails it's not there - despite being installed also in the standard location `/usr/...`. It wasn't instantly obvious to me how both those scripts handled the command line input, but both scripts exhibit the behaviour you're after.

Comment: I took a look, and they use the workaround I described above - so maybe there is no other way to do it.